# Dashcode: How to create a custom/new Project Template?

Tags: dashcode, project-template

I'm trying to customize the javascript that Dashcode uses.  So that I won't step on Apple's Project Templates, I want to make a custom project template that would appear as a choice after you click "New Project."  I have been able to modify one of the existing templates (like, Custom, Browser, Utility, RSS, and Podcast).
I can not, however, seem to add a new template to the list, like adding "JJ's Awesome New Cross Platform Template" as a choice.

I have tried copying the directory Plugins/TemplateWebCustom.wdgtTemplate and changing in Custom's Info.plist file the `com.apple.Dashcode.template.web.custom` to, say `com.apple.Dashcode.template.web.custom2` and in Resouces/project.plist updating the key value pair: `TemplateIdentifier ==>com.apple.Dashcode.template.web.custom`

Is it possible to add a new Project Template?  What the minimum steps?

Thanks,
JJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bunch of experimenting and searching, this doesn't appear possible. I could be wrong.

Comment: I will happily change the accepted-answer to anyone else that can prove me wrong!